# Combine Hibernate class with @Bindable for SwingBuilder without Griffon?

Tags: hibernate, groovy, griffon, bindable

I have implemented a back-end for my application in Groovy/Gradle, and am now trying to implement a GUI.

I am using Hibernate for my data storage (with HSQLDB) per 
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+Hibernate+with+Groovy
(with Jasypt for encryption) and it is working quite well.

I was wondering if there are any good tips for using @Bindable with, e.g., an @Entity class such as

```
@Entity class Book {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Author> authors
    public String title
    String toString() { "$title by ${authors.name.join(', ')}" }
}
```

or if I am:
(i) asking for Griffon
(ii) completely on the wrong track?

Thank you!
Misha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, looks like I can use @Bindable in a Hibernate @Entity!!

Misha